# Android get json array parsed by gson to custom object

Tags: android, json, object, arraylist, gson

I have a custom object called Img and Order:

```
public class Order {
private String name;
private String count;

public Order(String name, String count) {
    this.name = name;
    this.count = count;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public String getCount(){
    return count;
}
}
```

and

```
public class Img {
private String url;
private String name;
private String number;
private String id;

public Img(String url, String id, String name, String number) {
    this.url = url;
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.number = number;
}


public String getUrl() {
    if (url.contains("http://") || url.contains("https://")) {
        return url;
    } else {
        return "http://sampleurl.com/" + url;
    }
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getNumber(){
    return number;
}

public String getId(){
    return id;
}
}
```

and here are my json responses from server:

for Order:

```
{
"items": [
 {
 "id": {
 "kind": "Order",
 "appId": "s-contacts",
 "id": "5629499534213120",
 "parent": {
  "kind": "Contact",
  "appId": "s~contacts",
  "id": "4853444577853440",
  "complete": true
 },
 "complete": true
 },
 "name": "LCD",
 "count": 3,
 "kind": "orderendpoint#resourcesItem"
},
{
 "id": {
  "kind": "Order",
  "appId": "scontacts",
  "id": "5066549580791808",
  "parent": {
   "kind": "Contact",
   "appId": "s-contacts",
   "id": "4853444577853440",
   "complete": true
  },
  "complete": true
 },
 "name": "LCD",
 "count": 10,
 "kind": "orderendpoint#resourcesItem"
}
],
"kind": "orderendpoint#resources",
"etag": "\"oi1IHjqo\""
}
```

and for IMG:

```
 {
 "items": [
 {
 "id": "4853444577853440",
  "name": "aaaasssdddd",
  "phone": "45454545",
  "kind": "contactendpoint#resourcesItem"
 },
 {
 "id": "4919896311857152",
 "name": "Novy Kon",
 "phone": "522396",
 "kind": "contactendpoint#resourcesItem"
}
```

and I tried doing IMG with this code:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Img>>() {}.getType();
List<Img> records = new Gson().fromJson(json.getJSONArray("items").toString(), listType);
```

I am new to Gson and I can't get this to work, can you please help me putting it in a list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON for the IMG is invalid. I have taken the liberty to fix it:

```
{
  "items":[
    {
      "id":"4853444577853440",
      "name":"aaaasssdddd",
      "phone":"45454545",
      "kind":"contactendpoint#resourcesItem"
    },
    {
      "id":"4919896311857152",
      "name":"Novy Kon",
      "phone":"522396",
      "kind":"contactendpoint#resourcesItem"
    }
  ]
}
```

The custom object provided for the `Img` does not match your `JSON`. I have re-generated the `Img class` from the 'fixed' `JSON` using [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Img {

  @SerializedName("id")
  @Expose
  private String id;
  @SerializedName("name")
  @Expose
  private String name;
  @SerializedName("phone")
  @Expose
  private String phone;
  @SerializedName("kind")
  @Expose
  private String kind;

  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }

  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

  public String getKind() {
    return kind;
  }

  public void setKind(String kind) {
    this.kind = kind;
  }
}
```

To parse the `String json` into a `List<Img>` use the following `parseJson` code:

```
String json = "{\n" +
        "  \"items\":[\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\":\"4853444577853440\",\n" +
        "      \"name\":\"aaaasssdddd\",\n" +
        "      \"phone\":\"45454545\",\n" +
        "      \"kind\":\"contactendpoint#resourcesItem\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\":\"4919896311857152\",\n" +
        "      \"name\":\"Novy Kon\",\n" +
        "      \"phone\":\"522396\",\n" +
        "      \"kind\":\"contactendpoint#resourcesItem\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        "}";

private List<Img> parseJson(String json) throws JSONException {
    json = new JSONObject(json).getJSONArray("items").toString();
    Img[] data = new Gson().fromJson(json, Img[].class);
    return Arrays.asList(data);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to have kind parameter if I don't need it in code ?

Comment: You can remove the instance variable `kind` from the `Img` class if you don't need it and the code will still function correctly.